# How can I add background effects to this Caption of mine?

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of a problem, I have to add caption to my image which has a transparent background of opacity say 0.65 and color black, I have added a caption which has no background effects yet, help needed ASAP.
Thank You in advance.
Here's my code

```
 <div class="img-wrap"> <div style="300 px; font-size:20px; text-align:center;background-color= "ff0066;">
<img src="/gadgets.jpg" alt="alternate text" width="220px" height="200px" style="padding-bottom:1.0em;">
<a href="#">Gadgets and Accessories</a>
</div>
<div class="img-info">
<h3><a href="#">Gadgets & Accessories</a></h3>
<a href="#">Tablets</a><br>
<a href="#">Headphones</a><br>
<a href="#">External Optical Drives</a><br>
<a href="#">Flexible Keyboards</a><br>
<h3><a href="#">More...</a></h3>
</div>
</div>
```

The classes img-wrap and img-info contain styling code for some transitions for mouse hover effect, do I need to create a separate class for the caption thing?

Comment: You want to darken the image and display text, on hover?

Comment: No, like right now the cpation is "Gadgets and Accesories", I want to add a background to that caption....

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with a little demo of what you have now?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/e2HAE/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" alt="alternate text" width="220px" height="200px" />
    <a class="caption" href="#">Gadgets and Accessories</a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.img-wrap
{
    position:relative;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.caption
{
    width:220px; 
    font-size:20px; 
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:-25px;
    color:#fff;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition: all, 0.3s ease 0.2s;
}

img
{
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
img:hover + .caption
{
    visibility:visible;
    bottom: 2px;
    transition: all, 0.3s ease 0.2s;
}
```